# Use a field of a variable inside of a foreach in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, foreach, field

So I have a list of Active Directory users:

```
$users = Get-AdUser -Filter {Enabled -eq "True"}
```

What I want to do is group them based on their description since you have 3 possible descriptions in the whole user list.

However: I can't even seem to even use the `Description`field inside of a `foreach`:

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Write-Host $user.Name    
    Write-Host $user.Description
}
```

Their name shows but not their description.

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Get-ADUser` only returns specific properties by default. The description property is not one of these. To ensure it is returned you need to use the following parameter with `Get-ADUser`:

`-Properties Description`

> "This cmdlet retrieves a default set of user object properties. To retrieve additional properties use the Properties parameter." -
>    https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617241.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, can I ask you where to see the default properties of each cmdlet?

Comment: I don't think it's well documented, but if you pipe your results to the `get-member` cmdlet then you will see all the objects properties and methods. For example `get-aduser -filter * | get-member`

Comment: Actually it looks like its documented for `get-aduser` here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx . Also FYI you can get all properties returned by doing `-properties *`.

Comment: Thank you very much